# Barcode decoder for desktops

Tags: barcode-scanner

I am looking for a barcode scanner for a desktop application. We have over 2000 images with generated per month which need to be processed to decode barcode. Now most of these might or might not contain a barcode, in which case the sdk should reply with no barcode on the image.

Most of the barcode images are blurry so we need a robust sdk. I am aware of some open source libraries available like :Zxing, Zbar. There are some proprietary ones but mobile based.

What should be the best bet here?

Answer (score 2):

This may be useful to you...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10734/Reading-Barcodes-from-an-Image-II